# Is there an equivalent for ActiveRecord#find_by equivalent for C#?

Tags: c#, list, activerecord, collections

I'm originally a C# developer (as a hobby), but as of late I have been digging into Ruby on Rails and really enjoying it. Right now I am building an application in C#, and I was wondering if there is any collection implementation for C# that could match (or "semi-match") the find_by method of ActiveRecord.

What I am essentially looking for is a list that would hold `Rectangles`:

```
class Rectangle
{
    public int Width { get; set; }
    public int Height { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Where I could query this list and find all entries with `Height = 10`, `Width = 20`, or `name = "Block"`. This was done with ActiveRecord by doing a call similar to `Rectangle.find_by_name('Block')`. The only way I can think of doing this in C# is to create my own list implementation and iterate through each item manually checking each item against the criteria. I fear I would be reinventing the wheel (and one of poorer quality).

I am not necessarily trying to match the naming convention `find_by_...`, but rather to have the functionality of the method.

Any input or suggestions is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "Linq methods", namely [Where](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803.aspx), that were added in .NET 3.5 are pretty close to what you're looking for.

```
myCollection.Where(r => r.Name == 'Block')
```

Comment: Ah! Thank you so much. This is exactly what I was looking for but I didn't quite know what to search for.